# Is this C++ initialization valid?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Another developer wrote this and it looks strange to me. It runs at: http://codepad.org/jhnFpzGa

But I'm concerned because it gives a warning about not being able to make a default constructor on MSVC 10 (because of the reference obviously). Yet it works on MSVC too. The warning doesn't go away if I make it const UsageInfo& either.

```
typedef const char* UsageInfo[2];
UsageInfo usage_1 = {"foo1", "bar1"};
UsageInfo usage_2 = {"foo2", "bar2"};

struct JumpTableEntry
{
    const char* command;
    UsageInfo& usage; // {const char *usage,const char &details}
};

JumpTableEntry jumpTable_[] =
{
    {"1", usage_1},
    {"2", usage_2}
};

int main()
{
    cout << jumpTable_[0].usage[1] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which line are you confused about?

Comment: The code looks safe to me. The MSVC warning looks over-zealous. Their website states for this warning "You will not be able to create objects of this type.", which clearly is incorrect. On C++11 try adding `JumpTableEntry() = delete;` to the class.

Comment: @Cyber The question isn't about one single line?

Comment: I imagine that this code will produce the same warning, and it could be easier for people to consume: https://gist.github.com/sharth/9d36559566bb4fa26659

Comment: @Neil: post as an answer and I can accept it. So in other words, the only way to avoid the warning with this kind of code is with a /Wd flag? Is this code poorly styled?

Answer (score -1):

The warning seems valid.  It's *not* default-constructable.  If you want the warning to go away, I'd suggest one of the following:

- Declare a default constructor that's private that does something legal that doesn't produce warnings, but ultimately can't be reached.
- Explicitly delete the default constructor  `JumpTableEntry() = delete` This is not supported until VS2013 though - [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx)

You may be slightly confused here why it is prompting/warning for a constructor because you used the word `struct`.  Remember in C++, `struct`s and `class`es aren't usually different unless you make them such, except that the members are default `public` in `struct`s and default `private` in `class`es.

Comment: The first does not work because it prevents C-style array initialization.

Comment: And the warning is wrong, because the type is an aggregate, so aggregate initialization can be used to create instances, as in his example code.